# Making a list and retrieving it

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Here is a little bit of code suposed to create a list of expenses with name and amount:

```
def make_list():
    expense_list = []
            for count in range(1, 5):
                    print "expense number" + str(count) + ":"
                    name = raw_input(' enter expense name: ')
                    amount = raw_input(' enter expense amount: ')

            return expense_list
make_list()
```

What am I doing wrong? Even in interactive mode I can't seem to figure out how to get my item.

Comment: but even though  i'm  using what you advised me to do ,  lets say :
`my_list = make_list()
print my_list`
the output is   that :
"[]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong, you never actually add anything to your list and you don't assign the returned list to anything. Also, the "magic number" (`5`) isn't ideal. Try:

```
def make_list(n):
    expense_list = []
    for count in range(1, n+1):
        print "expense number {0}:".format(count)
        name = raw_input(' enter expense name: ')
        amount = raw_input(' enter expense amount: ')
        expense_list.append((name, amount))
    return expense_list
l = make_list(4)
print l
```

Comment: I would also say that "make_list" is not a very descriptive name; instead axeu5 should consider something like "query_expenses"

Comment: Thank you jonrsharpe  -
could you  explain  a little bit in details  i'm relatively new to python :P

Comment: @axeu5 what exactly is unclear? Is there a particular line or concept you don't understand?

Comment: `range(1, n+1)  when is the loop  is  supposed to  end  ?`

Comment: Have you tested it? Add a `print count` and see what happens.

Comment: yep i've tested it  it seem
`File "text1.py", line 9, in <module>
    l = make_list(4)
  File "text1.py", line 7, in make_list
    amount_list.append((name, amount))
NameError: global name 'amount_list' is not defined
`
this is the error i got ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo; fixed.